# SQLite and multi threading - DROP TABLE IS EXISTS

Tags: android

I have an application that syncronize data between SQL SERVER and SQLITE...

I'm using mutithreading to update few tables concurrently.....

I'm trying the follow below:

```
            // Drop table if exists before insert data
            dbHelper.dropTable(schema.getTable());

            // create new table
            dbHelper.createTable(schema);

            // begin transaction
            dbHelper.openTransaction();

                            //while() { do inserts }


            // end transaction
            dbHelper.endTransaction();
```

I'm using the same Dbhelper instance for all threads.... the first thread executes pretty well, but the seconds its crashing on "dropTable()", what 's wrong with my approach?

This is how I pass dbhelper to all threads:

```
    DbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper(getActivity());
    int max = mRequestList.size();
    for (int row = 0; row < max; row++) {
        DataReaderRequest request = mRequestList.get(row);
        DataUpdateTask task = DataUpdateManager.startUpdate(dbHelper,
                request);
    }
```

tks.

Comment: "I'm using mutithreading to update few tables concurrently" -- why? Done right, SQLite access is serialized anyway. "what 's wrong with my approach?" -- among other things, perhaps you did not look at LogCat to examine the Java stack trace to determine specifically why you are crashing.

Comment: CommonsWare is correct, also multithreading requires synchronized approach to shared data. It's like all of them try to poke same object in the same time. Collision is bound to happen

Comment: what about put a synchronized(){} statment before dropTable and after endtransaction??